# Destructing with default value

Tags: sorting, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have array of elements where some of labels are nulls:

```
let array= [ 
{category1:{id: 'aaa1', label:'bbb'}}, 
{category1:{id: 'aaa2', label:null}},
{category1:{id: 'aaa3', label:null}},
{category1:{id: 'aaa4', label:'ccc'}}, 
{category1:{id: 'aaa5', label:'ddd'}}, 
];
```

I want to sort this array by property label with understanding nulls as ''. so I have such code:

```
const sortingMethod = ({ category1: { label: elementALabel = '' } }, { category1: { label: elementBLabel = '' } }) => elementALabel.localeCompare(elementBLabel);
array.sort(sortingMethod );
```

Th problem is that elementAlabel sometimes seems to be null. Error is 'Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null'. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values in destructuring are only applied when the value is `undefined`.

If you need to use a default value for `null` use [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) with the **or** operator (`||`).

The expression `(elementALabel || '')` evaluates to the value of `elementALabel` if it's truthy, or to an empty string if the value is `falsy` (`null` in this case).

```js
const array = [{"category1":{"id":"aaa1","label":"bbb"}},{"category1":{"id":"aaa2","label":null}},{"category1":{"id":"aaa3","label":null}},{"category1":{"id":"aaa4","label":"ccc"}},{"category1":{"id":"aaa5","label":"ddd"}}];

const sortingMethod = ({ category1: { label: elementALabel } }, { category1: { label: elementBLabel } }) => (elementALabel || '').localeCompare(elementBLabel || '');
array.sort(sortingMethod)

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot it :).